# Line item state update in commercetools

Tags: java, commercetools

I need to update line item state to cancelled in commercetools, but I could not find any line item update action to update state in commercetools api, could you please help me?

Answer (score 1):

For the orders it's the transitionState action. Please see https://docs.commercetools.com/api/projects/orders#change-the-state-of-lineitem-according-to-allowed-transitions

Seems there is non for cart lineitems documented. It would be helpful to open a support ticket if necessary.